# Ansible: Skipping a line if <> is true

Tags: ansible

I have this Ansible playbook that I need some assistance with. Esentially in V1, I'm checking the RAM if it matches CPUid 8168 it passes and that works great but for v2 I have it check by the network speed, since they are both 1Gig connection, it tries to check it again but obviously fails it because they have different amount of RAM.  How can I tell Ansible to essentially say only check when `when: speed.stdout == '1000Mb/s' and is not cpudID=8168`

```
 - name: Check V1
  set_fact:
    total_mem: "{{memory.stdout }}"
  failed_when: "{{total_mem|int / 1000|int }} < 190"
  when: cpuid.stdout == '8168'

- name: Check v2
  set_fact:
    total_mem: "{{ memory.stdout }}"
  failed_when: "{{ (total_mem|int / 1000)|int }} < 250"
  ignore_errors: yes
  when: speed.stdout == '1000Mb/s'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Ansible documentation on [Conditionals](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_conditionals.html), multiple `when` statements can be combined with logical `and`...

```
when: speed.stdout == '1000Mb/s' and cpudID != 8168
```

... or specified as a list:

```
when:
  - speed.stdout == '1000Mb/s'
  - cpudID != 8168
```